# How to show sub-sub category of sub-category in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class TutorialCategory(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category_summary = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(default=1, blank=True) 

class TutorialSeries(models.Model):
    series_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    series_maincategory = models.ForeignKey(
        TutorialCategory, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    series_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    tutorial_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tutorial_content = models.TextField()
    tutorial_published = models.DateTimeField(
        "date Published", default=datetime.now())
    tutorial_series = models.ForeignKey(
        TutorialSeries, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    tutorial_slug = models.SlugField(default=1, blank=True)
```

As shown above `TutorialCategory` is main category, `TutorialSeries` is sub category and `Tutorial` is sub-sub-category. I created a simple view that shows sub categories of main categories, but don't know how to show the sub-sub categories of sub category.
Please check out `views.py` and `urls.py` if you can improve its quality and if there is an easy and better way of doing it. Anyway, this is view:

```
def single_slug(request, single_slug):
    matching_series = TutorialSeries.objects.filter(
        series_maincategory__category_slug=single_slug)

    series_urls = {}
    for i in matching_series.all():
        part_one = Tutorial.objects.filter(

tutorial_series__series_title=i.series_title).earliest("tutorial_published")
    series_urls[i] = part_one.tutorial_slug

return render(request, 'tutorial/sub-category.html', context={
    "tutorial_series": matching_series,
    'part_ones': series_urls
})
```

urls here:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home'),
    path('tutorial/<int:id>/', views.tutorial_detail, name='tutorial_detail'),
    path('<single_slug>/', views.single_slug, name='single_slug'),
]
```

the template that shows sub-category of main category:

```
   {% for tut, partone in part_ones.items %}

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ tut.series_title }}</h5>
            <p>{{ tut.series_summary }}</p>
            <a href="{{ partone }}">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Please help me how to do it and if you know any better way of doing it please let me know and help me. Thank you so much in advance.

edit: @ruddra
I changed `views.py` to this passing `matching_series`

```
def single_slug(request, single_slug):
    matching_series = TutorialSeries.objects.filter(
        series_maincategory__category_slug=single_slug)

    series_urls = {}
    for i in matching_series.all():
        part_one = Tutorial.objects.filter(
            tutorial_series__series_title=i.series_title).earliest("tutorial_published")
        series_urls[i] = part_one.tutorial_slug

    return render(request, 'tutorial/sub-category.html', context={
        "matching_series": matching_series,
        'part_ones': series_urls
    })
```

and replaced the previous template with yours. template here:

```
    {% for tutorial in matching_series %}
        {% for sub_cat in tutorial.tutorialseries_set.all %}
            {{ sub.series_title }}

            {% for sub_sub_cat in sub.tutorial_set.all %}
                {{ sub_sub_cat.tutorial_title }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Assuming the error is that the bit of your template you have posted doesn't show up on the page: have you checked if any of the `part_one` QuerySets in the view contain anything (just print it to the console)? Maybe the queries are simply empty and thus the `{% for %}` loop just never runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
 {% for sub_cat in matching_series %}
          {% for sub_sub_cat in sub_cat.tutorial_set.all %}
             {{ sub_sub_cat.tutorial_title }}
          {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Here I am assuming `matching_series` is being passed through context from view in `single_slug`. Then I am using [backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) between different models to fetch the data.

**Explanation:** Assuming there is object named `tutorial_category` which is instance of `TutorialCategory`. As there is ForeignKey from `TutorialSeries` to `TutorialCategory`, I can use `tutorial_category.tutorialseries_set.all()` or `.filter()` etc to fetch the tutorial series from `tutorial_category` object( As I am rendering it in template, I removed parenthesis after `all`). Similarly I fetch `Tutorial` from `TutorialSeries`.

Comment: Thank you @ruddra, I just edited my answer. 
I passed matching_series from view to template and replaced `backward relation` with my previous code. It didn't work, what I did wrong?

Comment: I made a mistake in my code. I have updated the answer. Please try the updated answer

Comment: same results @ruddra

Comment: what happens if you try with `{% for tutorial in tutorial_series %}`?

Comment: not working brother, now it even doesn't display the sub category.
You want to get and see all codes for review

Comment: That is weird, because the logic is same everywhere(using reverse relation). Are you using `related_name` in Tutorial model?

Comment: you did this `sub.tutorial_set.all` I think it should be okay without `related_name`

Comment: Yes. I wanted to know if you are using any so that in that case I had to change the query. Anyway, can you ensure the Tutorial models are correctly connected to subcategory(from database if possible)?

Comment: all models are properly connected. I just checked that.

Comment: `matching_series` is a `TutorialSeries` QuerySet - not a `Tutorial` QuerySet. `{% for sub_cat in tutorial.tutorialseries_set.all %}` fails because `tutorial` is actually an instance of `TutorialSeries` and has no `tutorialseries_set`.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice it was queryset of Tutorial Series(I was assuming it was Tutorial Category queryset, but I was wrong). Thanks for pointing out @CoffeeBasedLifeform . Noor, I have updated my answer.